# How to diagonalise when there is less parameters to estimate than data in the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm

Tags: least-squares, optimization, nonlinear-regression, calibration

I am trying to calibrate a Heston Model with 100 call options using this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08718.pdf.

In algorithm 4.1 on page 18, they define the dampening factor as: $$\mu_0 = \omega \text{max}\{diag(J_0)\}$$ Where $J_0$ is the gradient of the cost-function wrt the parameters you want to estimate. The issue that I am having is that $J_0$ is not a square matrix. I am trying to estimate 5 parameters, but using $n$ call options (in my case it’s 100 call options). I was told that I have to use singular value decomposition and that it is to prevent overfitting, but am not too sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. It's just an initial guess, see choice of damping factor in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg–Marquardt_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).
eg Matlab leaves it as an optional input parameter with default of 0.01 (https://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/least-squares-model-fitting-algorithms.html#f204)

normally $diag$ of a square matrix would mean the vector of the diagonal elements.

perhaps they meant the singular values which are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $J_0J_0^T$

or $diag\{J_0J_0^T\}$.

You can always email them...